# _wp_attachment_metadata is not being added to database when PDF files uploaded

Tags: database, post-meta, pdf

When I upload a JPG or PNG image, a _wp_attachment_metadata value is created in the database, but this is not the case for PDF files.

Is this the normal behavior or should the _wp_attachment_metadata be created for PDF files too?

I'm asking because there's a plugin I have installed that processes PDF files, and it's saying it's not able to do so due to missing metadata for the PDF files.

Here's an example of the difference in my database:

[image]

There are no PHP or server errors and I have checked on this with my host, and they said it's not an issue caused by any server settings on their part.

Has anyone had a similar issue and any idea how I can resolve this and get the When I upload a JPG or PNG image, a _wp_attachment_metadata value is created in the database, but this is not the case for PDF files.

Is this the normal behavior or should the _wp_attachment_metadata be created for PDF files too?

I'm asking because there's a plugin I have installed that processes PDF files, and it's saying it's not able to do so due to missing metadata for the PDF files.

There are no PHP or server errors and I have checked on this with my host, and they said it's not an issue caused by any server settings on their part. I've also tried PDFs from multiple different sources, so I don't think it's an issue with my specific PDFs.

Any idea about what might be causing this and what could possibly be done to get the _wp_attachment_metadata values to be created in the database for my PDF uploads?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's [the code in wp-admin/includes/image.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L565) that generates attachment metadata for PDFs. I think you'll have to add error_log() traces to it to see what's happening. I'd guess the problem is the "$editor = wp_get_image_editor( $file );" line returning an error, meaning your installed GD or ImageMagick (check which one you're using on System Health, Info) does not support PDFs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I actually had tried with both GD and ImageMagick enabled, and also with just one or the other enabled (and confirmed that in Site Health, Info before uploading a test PDF), but in all 3 cases, I get the same result. I will have to try adding error_log() traces, but don't have time at the moment. I will post back if I'm able to find anything. My host uses ImageMagick version 1802 and GD version 2.2.5 if it means anything to anyone. Site info does not list PDF among file types supported by GD and doesn't specify which formats are supported by ImageMagick.

Comment: @Joe Did you ever solve this? I, too, just discovered WordPress is not creating `_wp_attachment_metadata` for PDFs (only for thumbnails of a PDF). I see some other people online saying the same thing, and wonder if it's by design..